# Trying to find ways to update the "Description" parameter of an existing task in Task Scheduler from PowerShell

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-task-scheduler

I am trying to disable a task from Task Scheduler on multiple remote servers and while I do that I want to update the description of these tasks as well.

Though the command sets to work on schedule tasks are pretty straight forward like:
Get-Scheduledtask
Disable-ScheduledTask
Set-ScheduledTask
Etc.

I am unable to find parameters or command line that helps modify the Description of an existing task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I alluded to in the comments, this can be solved by:

1. Fetching the existing task instance
2. Modifying the description on the existing instance
3. Updating the task

```
# fetch existing task object
$task = Get-ScheduledTask "Pooja's Task"

# update the description
$task.Description = "New and improved description!"

# persist the change
$task |Set-ScheduledTask
```